# Calculate mean for variables in txt files

Tags: python, text-files, mean, ppp, troposphere

I need to calculate the mean for TRODRY and TROWET for this text file in python , since I have many files of this text file my file format is as follows:

```
%=TRO 0.01 EMR 23:208:83100 EMR 21:005:00030 21:006:00000 P SA20
+TROP/DESCRIPTION
*_________KEYWORD_____________ __VALUE(S)______________________
 ELEVATION CUTOFF ANGLE        7.5
 SAMPLING INTERVAL             30
 TROP MAPPING FUNCTION         VMF1_HT
 SOLUTION_FIELDS_1             TRODRY TROWET STDDEV TGNTOT STDDEV TGETOT STDDEV
-TROP/DESCRIPTION
+TROP/STA_COORDINATES
*SITE PT SOLN T __STA_X_____ __STA_Y_____ __STA_Z_____ SYSTEM REMRK
 SA20  A    1 P  4613949.845  2914211.009  3290440.104  IGb14 CSRS-PPP
-TROP/STA_COORDINATES
+TROP/SOLUTION
*SITE ____EPOCH___ TRODRY TROWET STDDEV TGNTOT STDDEV TGETOT STDDEV
 SA20 21:005:00030 2310.1  102.9   13.1   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00060 2310.1  102.9   12.9   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00090 2309.9  102.8   12.8   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00120 2309.8  102.8   12.6   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00150 2309.8  102.8   12.5   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00180 2309.8  102.8   12.4   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00210 2309.8  102.8   12.2   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00240 2309.9  102.8   12.1   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00270 2309.9  102.8   12.0   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
 SA20 21:005:00300 2309.9  102.8   11.9   -0.2    1.1   -0.1    1.0
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

https://onlinegdb.com/F75_kNQUJ

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from pathlib import Path
from statistics import mean
import csv


def worker(filename):
    data = False
    dry, wet = [], []
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file.read().splitlines():
            if '____EPOCH___' in line: data = True ; continue
            if not data: continue
            d, w = list(map(float, line.split()[2:4]))
            dry.append(d) ; wet.append(w)
    
    return filename, mean(dry), mean(wet)


files = Path('.').glob('*.txt')

with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as f, Pool() as pool:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['FILE', 'TRODRY', 'TRYWET'])
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, files):
        writer.writerow(result)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).